# Alternative to Investing.com

Tags: history, information, data, automation

Do you know of any alternative to Investing.com that allows me to get historical data by editing the URL? What I mean is that in Investing.com in the historical data page I get the form data retrieved by the method POST, but I need this to be via method GET, so that I can obtain only the information that I what (to then extract it to excel).

Comment: If this is a data-request you should probably explain what data you are after. Otherwise this belongs on some programming related SE.

Comment: I'm after historical prices...

Comment: not an answer, but many stock related financial services allow you to query with an API call to get this information. I'm assuming that flask/pandas in python or js (or js node) will get you the results you need fairly painlessly. The hard part will be finding a free API

Comment: If you know Python you can try this package https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/